# Docker Container interacting with 2 applications

Tags: java, mysql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I currently have a Java Application (.jar) in one container and I am using the docker-compose.yml to create an instance of a mysql database in a second container.

I want to know if it is possible for the container 1 to be able to interect with container 2, and be able to read/write to and from the mysql database

If it is possible, how would I go about this?

Answer (score 2):

Each container is like a virtual machine running inside your actual machine. And they have a virtual network that connects all of them. They can communicate with each other just like real machines on a real network.

When you specify links in your yaml, e.g. from the example from the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/):

```
web:
  links:
   - db
```

The result will be that inside the `web` container, the hostname `db` will resolve to the virtual IP of the `db` container. You can actually do `ping db` from within the `web` container and you should see the `db` container answer.

For mysql, assuming you named the mysql container `db` like in the example and linked your application to it like above, you'll simply have to write code that assumes this hostname. E.g. you'd connect to `jdbc:mysql://db:3306/databasename`. The port depends on what the image you use exposes.

It gets tricky once you want to have the containers running on actually different machines because you need a way to reach the virtual container network inside those machines. There are ways like proxies, forwarded ports, overlay networks, .. but that's beyond the capabilities of compose.

Comment: v2 of the docker-compose format supports networks and overlay networks. You can launch a [compose definition on a swarm](https://docs.docker.com/compose/swarm/).

Comment: @Matt True, but it's essentially swarm that reads the compose file and does it's thing. Not really a feature of compose.

Comment: There isn't much difference between compose launching something on plain docker compared to a swarm master.

Comment: Compose reads yaml config and maps that to appropriate API requests either using the [Docker Remote API](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/api/docker_remote_api/) or the [Docker Swarm API](https://docs.docker.com/swarm/swarm-api/), which are mostly the same API except for some node information.  The endpoint for compose is either a plain docker daemon or a docker swarm master.

Answer (score 0):

From the code point of view, the interaction is the same.

Your MySQL in Docker exposes the service on a particular hostname and port. The program using it uses that hostname and port.  Docker gives you the ability to configure this outside MySQL, but the Java code is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, linking containers over a network is standard functionality. 
As Peter Lawrey mentioned, you just configure the database connection in Java as normal with the name of service or docker container you want to connect to.

```
version: "2"

services:
  web:
    image: myapp
    networks:
      - myapp
  db:
    image: mysql
    networks:
      - myapp

networks:
  myapp:
    driver: bridge
```

Then you have a network to connect over

```
$ docker-compose start
Starting composenetworks_web_1
Starting composenetworks_db_1

$ docker exec composenetworks_web_1  ping db
PING mysql (172.22.0.3): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.22.0.3: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.093 ms
```